# How to set a pixel as transparent for 8-bit pngs when encoding with libpng?

Tags: image-processing, png, transparency, libpng

I'm trying to mark pixels as transparent when encoding rgb data to 8-bit png image (palette) using libpng. If I create a separate alpha channel in this case, the alpha channel is getting ignored. Is there a way to set the pixels as opaque or transparent when using 8-bit color palette ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark some palette index(es) as transparent, you must create a [tRNS](http://libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.tRNS) chunk.
In `libpng`, I guess you must use the function `png_set_tRNS()`